# VPN Client and IP tables

Tags: iptables, vpn, ppp, connman

I have a Debian 8.7 IoT Version on a Beaglebone Black device which is connected to the Internet using a GSM Modem. I installed a VPN client ([zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com/)) which joins a virtual network.

Something changes the default route and my Internet is no longer working.

```
 netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 zt0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
10.241.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 zt0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 zt0
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 usb1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 usb0
```

How can I ensure the default communication is routed over ppp0 and only 10.241.0.0/16 over zt0.

After adding the default GW, I get the following Table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 zt0
0.0.0.0         100.97.168.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 ppp0
```

I found out what adds the entry:

```
Oct 02 12:55:48 PTMH7 connmand[797]: zt0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
```

How can I prevent ConnMan from doing so?

Comment: Add ppp0 as your default gateway.

Comment: After setting up default gateway you check that "UG" flag in

Comment: @enZyme I added the result to the question. Thanks for the input

Comment: You can remove routing entries with `ip route del ...` (modern tool) or `route del ...` (old tool), but the question is who adds those routes in the first place. We can't answer this question because it depends on whatever gets executed on your system, and you are the only one with that system. So narrow it down: After which action does the route appear? Which scripts/programs are executed during this action? Etc. Renaming programs or scripts, and replacing them with a script that `echo`es all arguments and then calls the old one may help. So may `strace`.

Comment: @dirkt it looks like connmand adds the entry.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ConnMann. In your place, I'd either read up on ConnMann, or use something I'm familiar with instead.